# Website on iPad with X/Y px resolution looks ok, on PC with the same resolution it's horrible (too big)

Tags: javascript, android, css, ipad, responsive-design

I have a website which is mainly for mobile devices, but not only for them.

I already use the **RWD** approach. **I use percentage values in css** (none hard-coded `px`) and **I even scale the font-size with JavaScript**, so the result is always the same, regardless of screen size - on Android phone, iPhone, iPad... - it looks good (menu is 100% of width, it's height keeps the ratio, text is also visible).

But, when I preview that website on my PC (with the 24'' screen) it looks just like **nightmare**. Everything still keeps the ratio etc., but on such big screen (compared to iPhone/iPad), it just looks bad (menu button of 5x5 centimeters size...).

I would like to somehow stop expanding the sizes of elements at some point.

---

Note that `max-width/max-height` measured in pixels is **not a solution**. It's because some mobile devices has great px resolutions and still a very tiny screens (compared to 24''). At the same time, I can turn my monitor (24'') to render in 800x600 resolution. So px resolution says **nothing** about the size of screen (just to clarify it).

Image that I would use: `max-width: 900px` and that solves the problem with PC. But now I try to render the website on small (less then 18'') screen with resolution greater then 900px in width. And my menu has been scaled down (when I wanted it to fill the full width in the case of small screen).

**Real life example:**

The menu button looks ok when it's about 5 centimeters, I have 5 buttons and give each of them 20% of width (so the top menu is full width). When the screen is big, I want to have an left/right margins and menu centered, with buttons of about not more then 5 centimeters.

I could use media-query or css max-width like `max-width: 800px` and on my screen (24'', 1920x1080) then button will not go bigger then about 5 centimeters.

Fine. And now somebody runs my website on Samsung Galaxy Note Edge, which has about 6x3 '' screen size but 1600x2560px resolution. And my menu button suddenly is so small, that I cannot even see it (when I use px-based `max-width`).

---

Moreover, **I cannot rely on CSS `cm` unit**. They have been made with some assumption about dpi which looks ok on PC Windows 7 (for example), but on my HTC Android (for another example) `1x1cm` box is nothing like `1x1cm` box (and **no scaling was involved**).

---

So - **how to deal with it?**

I basically want i.e.: to make my button 20% of the screen's width (I will place 5 such buttons on the screen in one row, as top menu), but if the screen is bigger then 18'', I want to stop expanding it (some margin space will occur, but whatever). And it's absolutely regardless of the px resolution.

Comment: If you used media queries for your mobile styles, you could have applied a max-width/max-height only for screen sizes that are bigger than the mobile screen sizes.

Comment: @bigal - how so? media queries use just the same px (which tells nothing about real screen size) or cm (on which I cannot rely - details in my question). Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's preventing you from using px while achieving high resolution. Just because you're declaring it as px, the only issue would be your images not displaying at its best (text, background colours, borders etc shouldn't be an issue) but your images could be resolved by many other ways.

I suppose what I'm saying is that you shouldn't limit yourself using the wrong way in making it amazing for mobiles.

There are several ways out there to display retina images while using px.

Comment: An example solution (may not be the best) would be if you had an image you want to display as a button that's 200x300, what you would do is upload the image as 400x600 (doubled) and then styling it with a width and height of 200x300. There's also the whole thing where you let the browser detect what they are viewing the site with and it will serve them a different image in size/quality depending on it

Comment: @bigal I guess you are missing the point here. I'm not talking about the image resolution (you can assume I am talking about menu button that is just red `div` with some text). What I care about is to make that buttons (I have 5 of them) covering the full screen width (20% of screen width each) and keep the width/height ratio. But when the screen is bigger then 15cm, I don't want to scale the buttons more (let's have some margin then, better then having enormous big buttons). And 15cm screen can have 1920px as well as 800px so media-query based on px is not a case here.

Comment: So what's wrong with this: http://jsfiddle.net/xumxLzmb/10/

Comment: @bigal - try to watch it on e.g. Samsung Galaxy Note Edge (only 3'' width and 1600x2560px) - the menu buttons are almost invisible there (due to max-width: 960px which on PC results in nice few cm, but on that Samsung it's end up us like millimeters).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the header tag: `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />`?

width: The width of the virtual viewport of the device.

device-width: The physical width of the device's screen.

height: The height of the "virtual viewport" of the device.

device-height: The physical height of the device's screen.

initial-scale: The initial zoom when visiting the page. 1.0 does not zoom.

minimum-scale: The minimum amount the visitor can zoom on the page. 1.0 does not zoom.

maximum-scale: The maximum amount the visitor can zoom on the page. 1.0 does not zoom.

user-scalable: Allows the device to zoom in and out. Values are yes or no.

Comment: Yes, I was also trying with it as well. With just the same effect as I described in question. It only eliminates scaling.